# Button icon with possibility of passing parameters and get element

Tags: onclick, lightning-button

I have a IconButton , but to pass parameters to the JS, I use regular Icon with span like this :

```
 <span onclick="{!c.copyLink}"   data-theurl="{!item.path}"  data-caseid="{!item.id}" >
     <lightning:icon iconName="utility:link" size="x-small" aura:id="{!item.path}"  class="pointer"/>
 </span>
```

js:

```
 copyLink : function(component, event, helper) {
    var url = event.currentTarget.dataset.theurl;
    alert(url);
}
```

That is working perfectly, but I would like to change the Icon or its color.
To do that I think I need to get the icon element in the JS, but I cannot set Dynamic aurra:id and I cannot get the element using getSource because I'll get the span and not the LIgthning:icon.
Any ideas ?

Comment: you want to change the icon or its color on click?

Comment: yes but I don't know how to do that in this case , if it was a regular Lightning Button I could use : event.getSource().set("v.iconName" , 'utility:check');

Comment: so are you using aura:iteration to iterate over something?

Comment: yes it is a list of objects, so I cannot use Aurra:id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply assign index to button and then use that index to get other values from list

```
<aura:component  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="testlist" type="List" default="[1,2,3]" />

  <aura:iteration items="{!v.testlist}" var="item" indexVar="index">
     <lightning:buttonIcon value="{!index}" iconName="utility:link" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.copyLink }"  alternativeText="Settings (disabled)" title="Settings (disabled)" />
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

JS

```
({
    copyLink : function(component, event, helper) {
        event.getSource().set("v.iconName" , 'utility:check');
        console.log(component.get("v.testlist")[event.getSource().get("v.value")]);
}
})
```

in your scenario you can get both id,path like this

```
component.get("v.testlist")[event.getSource().get("v.value")].path
```